# Angular.isArray(data) returns false for an Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm using angular's $resource to get data from an API. My angular $resource is configured as follows:

```
Priorities : $resource (baseUrl + 'priorities/:priorityType/:uuid/all', {}, {
    query : {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
            priorityType : '@priorityType',
            uuid : '@uuid'
        },
        isArray: true
    }
})
```

However, when calling Priorities.query a $resource:badcfg error is thrown: "Expected response to contain an array but got an object". This exception means that the API returned an object but $resource is configured to receive an array - but the API is clearly returning an array:

```
[{"priority":"ONE","count":5,"globalCount":3037}]
```

Digging into the angular-resource.js, the exception is thrown here:

```
if (angular.isArray(data) !== (!!action.isArray)) {
  throw $resourceMinErr('badcfg', ...);
}
```

as expected `!!action.isArray` returns true, but strangely `angular.isArray(data)` returns false. What's going on here?

Comment: `but the API is clearly returning an array:` wait, is that _JSON_ you are getting? If so, you need to parse it first.

Comment: @vlaz this exception gets thrown before any transformResponse methods are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response needs to be transformed from json.

```
Mixin.staticMethod(Type, null, 'apiResponseTransformer', function (json) {
    var data = angular.fromJson(json);
    if (angular.isArray(data)) {
        return data.map(Type.build).filter(Boolean);
    }
    return Type.build(data);
})
```